# Detecting the browser language of choice with PHP

Tags: php, http, templates, language-features

I'm trying to implement this code to have different files to load for german, spanish or english browser languages of choice.
The case is that with my spanish IE I still get the english file.

```
<?php 
if (is_home()) {
  if (preg_match('/de-DE/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/german-navbar.php' );
  }
  elseif (preg_match('/es-ES/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/spanish-navbar.php' );
  }
  else {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/english-navbar.php' );
  }
}
```

I used both `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`, and `HTTP_USER_AGENT`.

This is the test of the site, if anyone wanted to check it, with german or spanish as a language of choice in the browser : http://paragraphe.org/janette/

I have my Firefox in english and is working nice, but I can't be sure the code is working for spanish and german cases.

I found the snippet [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620276/checking-browsers-language-by-php), but I'm a bit lost at this point.

Thanks so much for any input,

**EDIT:** the code does work in Firefox (but not IE).

Comment: What does die($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']); give you?

Comment: The page just loads as usual - but with the english default, as if the other conditionals had no meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, you can use the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59) extension for firefox to fake useragents and test it, though you'd have to fake the headers of the requests for HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, for instance with the [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967) extension (which also lets you change the user agents as well as the header)

oh, and it doesn't work in german:

```
Warning: include(/home/paragrap/public_html/janette/wp-content/themes/Janette/german-home.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/paragrap/public_html/janette/wp-content/themes/Janette/home.php on line 4

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/paragrap/public_html/janette/wp-content/themes/Janette/german-home.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/paragrap/public_html/janette/wp-content/themes/Janette/home.php on line 4
```

Comment: Wow, that worked excellent, I could check it and the code is working now. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

try this out please:

Just provide $availableLanguages as an array('en', 'de', 'es')

function get_client_language($availableLanguages, $default='en'){

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_language'])) {

    $langs=explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_language']);

    //start going through each one
    foreach ($langs as $value){

        $choice=substr($value,0,2);
        if(in_array($choice, $availableLanguages)){
            return $choice;

        }

    }
} 
return $default;
```

}