# Codeigniter MVC structure user parameter detection

Tags: codeigniter, localization

I am wondering about CI best practices

I need to have some code that detects the browser's language and assigns the appropriate language file.

does such code belongs under library or helper? ( if i am right helpers are php functions as opposed to libraries which are classes )

also what would be the best way to launch a class as opposed to just load it.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get language information from a browser with:

```
$this->input->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
```

Mine returns `en-US,en;q=0.8` so you will need to do some parsing to translate that into something useful to you.

But then you can set the language which CI uses to load language files with

```
$config['language'] = 'english';
```

where 'english' is the name of the folder in your `application/languages` folder which contains your language files.

You can do those things anywhere before your code runs. I'd recommend making a `application/libraries/MY_Lang.php` (application/core/MY_Lang.php in 2.0) and putting it in the constructor, cos then its always loaded before you use a language file.

Lastly should read [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html). But basically you retrieve a line from your language file with:

```
$this->lang->line('language_key');
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a function called [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) to detect user's browser. I think that the best practice is:

1. Set a front controller to get user's browser using Javascript.
2. Redirect the user to an appropiate function, to set language and load your main view.

Anyways, on Google I found a few snippets:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
```

And from here, on StackOverflow: [Checking browser's language by php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620276/checking-browsers-language-by-php)