# Browser language and Facebook button

Tags: jquery, facebook, browser

I have on my wordpress website the Zillashare plugin in order to have the facebook like button below each of my posts, like this : [SoCatchy!](http://socatchy.net/percy-lau-mystery-and-creation/)

But I can't manage to settle the PHP plugin file to have the Facebook like button adapting to the browser user language.
It always displays the "Like", but I want it to adapt to each browser.

Here is the function Facebook code :

```
if($options['show_facebook']) $output .= '<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));</script>';
    if($options['show_google']) $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var po = document.createElement("script"); po.type = "text/javascript"; po.async = true;
      po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
    </script>';
```

But I don't know if I had to add something to my function or to quit something.

I thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'like' button is not just a button but also a symbol fro facebook. Similiar to i will google something.

Maybe disabeling the language support and always using english might be a possibility?

and i found some another solution.. but i didnt checked it . if you want you can try it [here](http://help.addshoppers.com/customer/portal/articles/688069-how-to-change-the-language-of-the-facebook-like-button-).

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't manage to settle the PHP plugin file to have the Facebook like button adapting to the browser user language. It always displays the "Like", but I want it to adapt to each browser.

That won’t happen automatically. Which language the Facebook social plugins use when they’re embedded using the JS SDK, depends on the `locale` used to load the SDK itself:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                                 ^^^^^
```

You’re loading it in US English here, so that’s the language you’re getting your like button in as well.

So you will have to detect the language to use first – if you don’t know how that can be done, check other SO questions on that topic, f.e. this one, [Checking browser's language by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620276/checking-browsers-language-by-php)

Then you should check if that language is available as a locale for the JS SDK – if so, use it, if not, default back to US English or whatever you prefer in that case.

More info on the supported locales and the topic of Localization of the JS SDK you can find here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#localization